# operator overloading error in C++ when trying to compare strings

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload an operator `<<` in a class I created which compares two strings no matter the casing. Here is my bool operator

```
friend bool operator <<(const string& member, const string& player) {
  return toLowerCase(member) == toLowerCase(player);
}
```

The program returns an error at this point in my code

```
current->name << member
```

Now current is a pointer to a node which contains a string name and member is a string that is passed by reference when the user is prompted. The error I get is

```
invalid operands to binary expression('string'(aka'basic_string<char>') and 'string')
```

Comment: Using `<<` for a comparison definitely violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @juanchopanza and that even with standard library types; pity the poor guy trying to print his strings to `std::cout`...

Comment: How have you implemented toLowerCase function?

Comment: printing out if two string are equal would be: cout << (str1 << str2) << endl; Not very practical

Comment: it belongs to an external library which I included

Comment: Are you sure it takes std::string as input and returns std::string as output?

Comment: yh it returns the string object

Comment: @H2CO3 uh, yes we can. Hopefully we have access to either the source code, or some documentation specifying the semantics of the operators. Sure, if I don't look it up, then I can't know what an operator might do, but the same is true for functions.

Comment: @jalf But at least functions have meaningful names (at least in code that makes sense). How the heck am I supposed to know what secondary/tertiary/quaternary meaning one has given to poor `operator <<` once again? If it's not obvious at first glance, it's wrong. (That's why operator overloading is a horrible feature of C++).

Comment: @otch92 Is the declaration of the operator visible at the point where you use it? Is it in a header file you include before using the operator?

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is called "principle of least astonishment"

Comment: @SigTerm: "POLS" is also well-recognised. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @H2CO3: but then you are comparing "functions written by sane programmers" against "operators written by insane programmers". Sure, you can assign arbitrary meanings to an operator such as `<<`, but you can also assign arbitrary meanings to a function like `CreateFile`. It could send an email to NASA, if you want to implement it in that way. Both with operators and functions, you have to assume some kind of sanity and honesty from the person who implemented it.

Comment: @jalf Don't take me wrong, it was not my intent, and I see what you mean. Surely there are conventions, my point is only that the semantics of an operator are much less obvious or self-explanatory as a well-named function.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think it depends. The semantics of `operator+` for `int`s are pretty obvious and self-explanatory, aren't they? I agree that there are a lot of "bad" operator overloads out there, and that *they* are much less obvious than a well-named function would have been, but that's still comparing apples to oranges. Overloading an operator that is not suitable for the semantics you want is just as dumb as giving your function a misleading name. People still do it far too often, sure, but I don't think that makes operator overloading as a language feature *bad*.

Comment: @jalf Yes, they are quite obvious. Yes, people misuse operator overloading, the only thing I'm saying here is that operator overloading is much easier to get wrong that functions. (But I know, nobody forces me to do that, nor does anybody force me to write C++ code... :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests it's not picking up your overload, but trying to use the built-in bitshift operator on `string`s (and failing, of course). I'm not sure why, given the information you've supplied.

Anyway, a much better idea would be to use a non-member, non-operator `compare()` function -- using `operator<<` to compare strings is just going to confuse the hell out of anybody looking at your code (even you, in a couple of years time).

Answer (score 0):

Move that declaration out of your class and remove `friend` keyword:

```
bool operator <<(const string& member, const string& player)
{
     return toLowerCase(member) == toLowerCase(player);
}
```

[Live code.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7e15604488c57a8)